# UITextField inside a UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield

I have UITextField inside a UITableView. I've set the delegate of the text view in the cellForRowAtIndexPath method of my UITableView as follows

```
cell.textField.delegate = self;
```

but when I finished editing and press "done" I didn't get anything in my delegate method as shown below. What could be the reason?

```
-(void) textFieldDidEndEditing: (UITextField * ) textField {    
NSLog(@"here");
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `textFieldDidEndEditing:` method is called after the text field resigns first responder status. To get the text field to resign first responder status, send it a `resignFirstResponder` message. A good place to do that is in the text field delegate's `textFieldShouldReturn:` method. It would look something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

When the user taps the "Done" key, the `textFieldShouldReturn:` method will get called, causing the text field to resign first responder status and `textFieldDidEndEditing:` to be called.